# Was there a TV show that returned for another season after declared as finished?

Tags: production

TV shows usually run for several seasons (might also be one), then finished, with the production company officially declaring there won't be more seasons. Fair enough.

However, I wonder if there were any TV shows that "returned from the grave", i.e. got back to another full season after being officially finished?

Not talking about "reunion chapter" which is probably common, or about TV shows aborted mid-season then bought shortly after by different producer, but about TV shows which had at least one full season, finished "gracefully", then came back after a while for whole new season.

<sub><sup>Yes, I know Friends *almost* made it last year (that's what inspired the question. :))</sup></sub>

Comment: I'm assuming you're excluding shows that were cut short and then brought back like *Arrested Development*?

Comment: @Catija hmm... wanted to mention this and forgot, thanks. Indeed I'm excluding those.

Comment: Do you consider the new season of *The X Files* to count? Or *Twin Peaks*? or *Doctor Who?*...

Comment: @Catija yes! Totally forgot about X-Files... even the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files) says "Revival:
January 24, 2016 – present". lol

Comment: Don't forget about futurama, prison break and 24 (brought back under the name of 24: Legacy)

Comment: Let's not let it become an open-ended list, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yeah, question is how to limit it? "First correct answer wins"? Not sure about the site rules/customs yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could limit this question and it's likely to provide a list of shows that were revived (years later), but at least we've established the answer is yes. And it feels like this is a common thing at the moment. Will and Grace will also be back this september after being gone for 11 years.

Comment: What is permitted for "ended", and how much time is required?  The writers ended _Stargate SG-1_ with a bookend finale in Season 8, then it got renewed for two more seasons anyway.

Comment: @Izkata I'd say at least two years, otherwise it might still be considered as part of the original plan, in my opinion. (e.g. planned move to draw attention.)

Comment: Would [Scrubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrubs_(TV_series)) fit your definition? It came back for a ninth season with new cast members after its [finale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Finale)?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni not sure, if the only same thing is the name then no. If only the cast is different and they kept most other things intact then yes, it fits. :)

Comment: Not sure if it fits, but wasn't Californication filmed in a way that each season could be the "final season". In a way each season was finished, but they kept making more. Not truly finished, but kinda.

Comment: @WilliamMariager no. I ask about shows that were officially ended, announced as finished, etc.

Comment: The question isn't asking for a list. It's asking whether it's happened. Siting examples is purely to show that it has occurred. I don't think further examples are necessary as the answer has been shown to be "yes".

Comment: @Catija well, what should we do now then? Close the question? I admit, now it seems off topic. :-(

Comment: Somebody has made a [nice big list on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls069402608/)

Comment: I'm saying it's not off topic.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley huh, feel free to post that as answer, copying the names.

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you explain why Arrested Development doesn't meant you criteria?  `but about TV shows which had at least one full season, finished "gracefully", then came back after a while for whole new season` seems to apply since the show did end somewhat gracefully. They knew it was ending and wrapped up the show, only to continue the story several years later.  If this doesn't apply, could you edit your question to explain why this isn't a good answer

Comment: @psubsee2003 I admit I'm not sure, Catija said "cut short and then brought back", so assumed it wasn't ended gracefully.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll admit it was "cancelled", but Fox cancelled it with enough noticed that the producers were able to wrap up the existing story line.  Then it came back many year later.  Seems to apply here.

Comment: @psubsee2003 fair enough, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Another way to turn up lots of examples would be to look at game shows...

Comment: Do you draw a difference between "brought back" after a short time, and a generation gap reboot?  Programmes with a ~20 year gap may be brought back by adults who were kids when watching the first round.

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but it reminded me of HIMYM, where they inserted a whole extra season before the end.

Comment: What about *Babylon 5* and *Buffy The Vampire Slayer* where the story lines were completed and then more seasons were approved?

Comment: @ToddWilcox nope, sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't just leave all of the added restrictions to the question in the comments, you should edit them into the question. Comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I did. "story lines were completed and then more seasons were approved" is something I never asked for, it's not related at all.

Comment: You wrote a comment where you specify at least a two year hiatus, but that's not in the text of the question. That's just one example.

Answer (score 12):

There's actually a recent spate of this. I don't know that there are a ton of them but there are three that come to mind.

*[The X-Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files)* ended gracefully and just came back for two new seasons.

> The X-Files is an American science fiction drama television series created by Chris Carter, which originally aired from September 10, 1993 to May 19, 2002 on Fox. The program spanned nine seasons, included 202 episodes, and a feature film of the same name. Later in 2008, a second film was made and preceded a tenth-season revival, which consisted of six episodes, in 2016. The revival premiered on January 24, 2016. In April 2017, Fox officially announced that The X-Files would be returning for an eleventh season of ten episodes, which would air in the 2017–18 television season.

Additionally, the iconic David Lynch show *[Twin Peaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks)* aired an additional season (in addition to a film) starring many of the same people.

> In October 2014, Showtime announced that the show would return as a limited series. Also known as Twin Peaks: The Return, the limited series premiered on May 21, 2017 and was written by Lynch and Frost and directed by Lynch. Many original cast members, including MacLachlan, have returned.

I'd also say that *[Doctor Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who)* fits this description as well. It ended back in the 70s and was restarted in 2005 after a 26 year hiatus.

> The programme originally ran from 1963 to 1989. There was an unsuccessful attempt to revive regular production in 1996 with a backdoor pilot, in the form of a television film titled Doctor Who. The programme was relaunched in 2005, and since then has been produced in-house by BBC Wales in Cardiff.

Comment: Dr who ended its original run in 1989 meaning it was a 16 years hiatus.

Comment: @Sarriesfan It's Sunday. I take a break from math on Sundays.

Comment: There are multiple instances of this in Indian TV network. Some TV shows have been returned after 7-8 years and some after 3-4 years.

Answer (score 4):

Arrested Development, another series on Fox was canceled and was thought to be [completely dead](http://www.looper.com/18313/real-reasons-arrested-development-canceled/) (second link [here](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2013-05-24/a-huge-mistake-arrested-development-cast-criticise-foxs-2006-cancellation)).

The show was later revived on Netflix for a 4th season in 2013 (7 years after the original cancellation) and a 5th season is in production for 2018.

Comment: The OP asked for series which were declared finished, not canceled.

Comment: @KarlRichter given that it took 7 years i would say that it was almost dead

Comment: I used this example in the comments specifically to ask if it counted and the OP said it doesn't.

Comment: @Catija thanks, missed the comment discussion,   I assumed all relevant details would be in the question itself.  Unless it's there, I assume this answer is accurate

Comment: The question clearly says "TV shows which had at least one full season, finished "gracefully", then came back after a while for whole new season." Ending mid-season doesn't sound like a "gracefully" ending.

Comment: @Catija but it didn't end mid season.  The show finished it's 3rd season.  It might have been an abrupt ending,  but it tied up the loose ends.  How can that not be "finishing gracefully".  Granted the ending was earlier in the season than most series, but no one said a series must end in May with 20+ episodes

Comment: Tying up loose ends because you've been told the series is ending (before it was planned) is just polite. It only had 13 episodes, at least 5 fewer than either of the prior two seasons.

Comment: @Catija The [OP seems to have admitted](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77777/was-there-a-tv-show-that-returned-for-another-season-after-declared-as-finished/77782?noredirect=1#comment127618_777770) he might have been wrong initially

Answer (score 3):

**Family Guy** was cancelled twice by Fox (though the first cancellation was [reprieved two months later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Guy#Early_history_and_cancellation)). The second time Fox cancelled the show they intended to farm it out to a buyer purely for repeat fees, but the popularity this generated led to Fox commissioning another run of episodes. The fourth series premiered more than three years after the third. According to Wikipedia, this was ["the first revival of a television show based on DVD sales"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Guy#Cult_success_and_revival).

The cancellation and revival were the source of a joke at the start of the newly commissioned fourth series, in the episode [North By North Quahog](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Family_Guy/Season_4#North_by_North_Quahog), and of a comment by Seth MacFarlane in the [100th Episode Celebration](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Family_Guy/Season_6#100th_Episode_Celebration).

Comment: The OP asked for series which were declared finished, not canceled.

Answer (score 3):

From the list ["TV Revivals"](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls069402608/) by IMDB user deano11, here are a few examples. For most of these, I don't know if the original "ended gracefully". In a lot of the older shows, especially sitcoms, there was not much long-term story arc, so the final episode being just another normal episode could be considered a graceful ending.

The New Leave It to Beaver - 20 years after Leave It to Beaver ended.

The Munsters Today - similar time frame to the Beav.

The New WKRP In Cincinnati: I actually remember watching this one. (Several original cast members were replaced; does that still count?)

Twilight Zone and Outer Limits - if you want to count anthologies. Twilight Zone has had 2 revivals *and* a movie.

Dallas (21-year gap: 1991-2012)

Mission: Impossible (15-year gap: 1973-1988)

90210 (8-year gap: 2000-2008)

I guess you won't allow Star Trek as having ended gracefully since they didn't get their 5 years in.

Answer (score 3):

**Knight Rider** originally ran for 4 seasons from 1982-86 and was brought back in 2008/2009 for a Reboot, but then cancelled again after one Season.

**Hawaii Five**-O ran from 1968-80 and was rebooted in 2010 (still ongoing).

Both feature the descendants of the original protagonists due to the time difference in between. Hawaii Five-O does regularly pick up stuff and references from the old series.

Knight Rider was cancelled due to low views, but ended somewhat gracefully.

Hawaii Five-O was resolved gracefully and ended with the last Episode.

**Gilmore Girls** ran from 2000 - 2007 and returned for another Season in 2016 on Netflix. The miniseries was broadcast in 2020 on The CW and UP TV. The original series was finished and resolved gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

[***Jericho***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0805663/)..cancelled twice, then came back as a comic book series!

> Jericho ran on CBS from September 20, 2006, to March 25, 2008. It was canceled after its first full season, because of poor ratings. A fan campaign persuaded the network to bring the show back for another season, of seven episodes, after which it was canceled again.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jericho_(2006_TV_series))

Comment: Ouch. Still hurts when I recall this. Such a great potential. Since it was aborted, not sure it qualifies for what I asked here though.